# Printing c# reserved keywords in colors

Tags: c#, printing, colors, margin

OK in my notepad like program, I want to print the text like code so I want the reserved words to be printed in blue and the text to be within the margins any ideas how to do this??
This is what i have so far.

```
    int charPag = 0;
        int linPag = 0;
        Font rodFont = new Font("Courier New", (float)10.0);

        e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, txtMain.Font, e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic, out charPag, out linPag);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, txtMain.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charPag);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Bottom, e.MarginBounds.Right, e.MarginBounds.Bottom);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(numPag.ToString(), rodFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Right - (numPag.ToString().Length * rodFont.SizeInPoints), e.MarginBounds.Bottom + 5);
        if (stringToPrint.Length > 0)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            numPag++;
        }
```

Comment: why reinvent what is already out there and available for free? use Scintilla.NET as textArea in your application... http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Because it's for school, and I have to do it myself.(unfortunately)

Comment: Erm, wait, you are asking for help to do it yourself?  Use the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a HashSet holding the reserved words

```
public HashSet<string> _reservedWords = 
    new HashSet { "if", "else", "class", "..." };
```

Then you will have to find the identifiers contained in a text line. Identifiers are character sequences beginning with a letter or an underscore and consisting of letters, underscores and digits.

Once you have found an identifier, check whether it is a reserved keyword or not

```
bool reserved = _reservedWords.Contains(word);
```

Comment: The problem is how to find the identifiers.
I am using the split(' ') but then if the person introduces 2 or more spaces it only reads as 1.
I am I explaining it right?

Comment: You can specify this with the string split options, `s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: If the string can contain punctuations and other special characters, you can use Regex to find words, `var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+");`. `foreach (Match match in matches) { ...}`. The matches tell you the positions (`match.Index`) and lengths (`match.Length`) of the words and the words themselves (`match.Value`).